# Indoor tracking app using IMU

Tags: android, tracking, android-sensors, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to create an Android indoor tracking App using IMU.

Right now my app is based on accelerometer and software sensor ROTATION_VECTOR which is suposed to by created by fusing data from ACCELEROMETER, GEOMAGNETIC_FIELD and GYROSCOPE. I am using accelerometer for detecting steps and ROTATION_VECTOR sensor for orientation. When the step is detected, I take the data from ROTATION VECTOR, calculate the angle difference between starting and curent angle, calculate the new coordinates and display the new location.(I use steps with fixed length)

The problematic part is the accuarcy of the orientation. I read some papers which suggest use Kalman filter, However it's still a mystery for me how to implement it.

I would be very gratefull if someone help me with this problem. Suggest some tutorials how to understand Kalman filter, or show me the way how to improve the accuracy of my app.

Thanks a lot.

My code:

```
package com.example.jozef.gyrouhol;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Gyro extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mRotationSensor, mStepSensor;

    private static final int SENSOR_DELAY = 1000;
    private static final int FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS = -57;
    private double norming;

    private ObjectHandler mData;

    private int count = 0;
    private int pmin = 0, pmax=0;
    private long actualTime = 0;

    private float mStartingAngle;
    private HouseBackground myView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myView = new HouseBackground(this);
        setContentView(myView);

        try {

            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
            mStepSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, SENSOR_DELAY);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mStepSensor,SENSOR_DELAY);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hardware compatibility issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mData = new ObjectHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        if (event.sensor == mRotationSensor) {

            update(event.values);
        }

        if(event.sensor == mStepSensor) {

            norming = Math.sqrt((event.values[0]*event.values[0])+(event.values[1]*event.values[1])+(event.values[2]*event.values[2]));
            stepCount(norming);
        }
    }

    private void update(float[] vectors) {

        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);

        float[] orientation = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientation);

        float xdeg =  orientation[0]* FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
        mData.ObjectHandlersetAngle(xdeg);
    }

    protected void onPause() {

        mSensorManager.unregisterListener((SensorEventListener) this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void stepCount (double mNorming){
        if (norming > 10.403 )

            pmax = 1;

        if (norming < 8.45)

            pmin = 1;

        if (pmax == 1 && pmin == 1) {

            if (count == 0){
                count++;
                actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(mStartingAngle == 0)
                {
                    mStartingAngle = mData.ObjectHandlergetAngle();
                }
                myView.newPointAdd((int) (myView.getLastX()-Math.round(93*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(mData.ObjectHandlergetAngle()-mStartingAngle))) ), (int) (myView.getLastY()-Math.round(93*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(mData.ObjectHandlergetAngle()-mStartingAngle)))));

            }

            else {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - actualTime > 400) {
                    count++;
                    actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int xnew = (int) (myView.getLastX()-Math.round(93*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(mData.ObjectHandlergetAngle()-mStartingAngle))));
                    int ynew = (int) (myView.getLastY()-Math.round(93*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(mData.ObjectHandlergetAngle()-mStartingAngle))));
                    myView.newPointAdd(xnew,ynew);
                }
            }

            pmin = 0;
            pmax = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    final float alpha = 0.97f;

    synchronized (this) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            mGravity[0] = alpha * mGravity[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGravity[1] = alpha * mGravity[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGravity[2] = alpha * mGravity[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];

        }

        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            float azimuth = orientation[0]; //in radians
            azimuth = azimuth * 360 / (2 * (float) Math.PI); // -180 to 180


        }
    }
}
```